# formatting inconsistent date data with pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm wondering how I might approach the problem of inconsistent data formats with pandas. Initially I used regular expression to extract a date from a large data set of urls. That worked great however there is an inconsistent date format among the extracted dates:

```
dates
20140609
20140624
20140404
3/18/14
3/10/14
3/14/2014
20140807
20140806
2014-07-18
```

As you can see there is an inconsistent formatting of the date data in this dataset. Is there a way to fix this formatting so that all the dates are of the same format?

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 122270 entries, 0 to 122269
Data columns (total 4 columns):
id                  119534 non-null float64
x1                  122270 non-null int64
url                 122270 non-null object
date                122025 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 4.7+ MB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) it seems man/woman enough to handle your inconsistent formatting:

```
In [77]:

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Data columns (total 1 columns):
dates    9 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 144.0 bytes
In [78]:

df
Out[78]:
       dates
0 2014-06-09
1 2014-06-24
2 2014-04-04
3 2014-03-18
4 2014-03-10
5 2014-03-14
6 2014-08-07
7 2014-08-06
8 2014-07-18
```

For your sample dataset `to_datetime` works fine, if it didn't work for you it will be because you have some formats that it can't convert, you can either set the param `coerce=True` which will set any values that cannot be converted to `NaT` or `errors='raise'` to report any problems.

Comment: I actually already tried that and it didn't work I suppose I should have mentioned that

Comment: Sorry are you saying you don't get the same output as mine or that you want a different format?

Comment: That I don't get the same output as you, in fact it just spits out the original input unchanged

Comment: So what exactly is your data currently? Are they still strings or are they all datetime? They looked like strings to me

Comment: I added the df.info() in the original post so you can see my data types. Looks like my data column is of type object?

Comment: They look like string to me so are you saying that no change occurs after calling `to_datetime`? One problem could be that not all your dates are convertible so you could either set param `coerce=True` which will set these to `NaT` or set `errors='raise'`

Comment: Great it just needed to be coerced. Maybe just add that to your answer for completeness and then I can accept it? Thanks for the help mate!