# Pandas Inconsistent date-time format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, string-to-datetime

I started using pandas library about a fortnight back. Learning the new features. I would appreciate help on the following problem.

I have a column with dates in mixed format. These are the 2 formats present

1. `mm/dd/yyyy`
2. `dd/mm/yyyy`

An extract from the dataset :-

```
Dates  
6/5/2016  
7/5/2016  
7/5/2016  
7/5/2016  
9/5/2016  
9/5/2016  
9/5/2016  
9/5/2016  
5/13/2016  
5/14/2016  
5/14/2016
```

I am struggling to convert these to a common format. I tried using pandas's 'to_datetime'. It does not work.
I am also not sure how will using regular expressions help in this case.

Another piece of information. The dates are in sorted order. Can something be done using info.

#### EDIT1:

I understand that it is impossible to distinguish between 6/4/2016 and 5/6/2016, if we look at them alone. However, I was hoping that the fact the dates are in ascending order and the actual dataset is spread for over a year, there would be a method to make sense of it. Is anyone aware of a function which can make sense of the format given the fact that the dates are in ascending order ?

EDIT2:
Sample of 2 months :- April and May 2016. Please note that there is no pattern. So please do not suggest any solution based on patterns of the data below.

> 4/1/2016
> 4/1/2016
> 4/3/2016
> 4/3/2016
> 3/4/2016
> 4/4/2016
> 4/4/2016
> 4/5/2016
> 4/5/2016
> 4/7/2016
> 4/7/2016
> 4/8/2016
> 4/8/2016
> 4/14/2016
> 4/16/2016
> 6/4/2016
> 7/4/2016
> 8/4/2016
> 11/4/2016
> 11/4/2016
> 11/4/2016
> 11/4/2016
> 11/4/2016
> 12/4/2016
> 12/4/2016
> 12/4/2016
> 13/4/2016
> 13/4/2016
> 13/4/2016
> 13/4/2016
> 14/04/2016
> 15/4/2016
> 16/4/2016
> 16/4/2016
> 18/4/2016
> 18/4/2016
> 19/4/2016
> 19/4/2016
> 20/4/2016
> 20/4/2016
> 21/4/2016
> 21/4/2016
> 21/4/2016
> 22/4/2016
> 23/4/2016
> 23/4/2016
> 25/4/2016
> 25/4/2016
> 26/4/2016
> 26/4/2016
> 26/4/2016
> 26/4/2016
> 26/4/2016
> 26/4/2016
> 29/4/2016
> 29/4/2016
> 29/4/2016
> 30/4/2016
> 2/5/2016
> 2/5/2016
> 3/5/2016
> 3/5/2016
> 3/5/2016
> 3/5/2016
> 4/5/2016
> 5/4/2016
> 5/4/2016
> 5/4/2016
> 6/5/2016
> 6/5/2016
> 7/5/2016
> 7/5/2016
> 7/5/2016
> 9/5/2016
> 9/5/2016
> 9/5/2016
> 9/5/2016
> 10/5/2016
> 10/5/2016
> 11/5/2016
> 11/5/2016
> 12/5/2016
> 5/13/2016
> 5/14/2016
> 5/14/2016
> 5/15/2016
> 5/16/2016
> 5/16/2016
> 5/16/2016
> 5/16/2016
> 5/16/2016
> 5/16/2016
> 5/16/2016
> 5/17/2016
> 5/17/2016
> 5/18/2016
> 5/18/2016
> 5/19/2016
> 5/19/2016
> 5/20/2016
> 5/20/2016
> 5/20/2016
> 5/20/2016
> 5/20/2016
> 5/21/2016
> 5/23/2016
> 5/23/2016
> 5/23/2016
> 5/23/2016
> 5/23/2016
> 5/23/2016
> 5/24/2016
> 5/24/2016
> 5/25/2016
> 5/26/2016
> 5/26/2016
> 5/26/2016
> 5/27/2016
> 5/27/2016
> 5/27/2016
> 5/27/2016
> 5/27/2016
> 5/27/2016
> 5/27/2016
> 5/28/2016
> 5/30/2016
> 5/30/2016

Comment: what is a fortnight?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516616/formatting-inconsistent-date-data-with-pandas - I have checked this post..However this does not work for my data-set even using error='coerce'.

Comment: Are you sure it is inconsistent? If yes, I think it is impossible distinguish in some dates e.g. between `6/5/2016` and `5/6/2016` . First is May or June?

Comment: @jezrael : Firstly, thank you for your kind reply ! yes, the dates column is inconsistent. This data is maintained on a spreadsheet. People have not followed a consistent date-format. 
I understand that it is impossible to distinguish between 6/4/2016 and 5/6/2016, if we look at them alone. However, I was hoping that the fact the dates are in ascending order and the actual dataset is spread for over a year, there would be a method to make sense of it.

Comment: @Amit - How many dates are in one month? How many are broken? 5%, 50%?

Comment: @Amit - Can you add sample for two months?

Comment: @jezrael : sample code added. For april month, the dominant format is dd/mm/yyyy but for may it is mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that there are ambiguous dates in your dataset (do you parse it as mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy if it could be either?? *(I've been here, and we decided just to pick what the majority seemed to be; essentially the dataset was compromised... and we had to treat it as such).*

---

If it's a Series then hitting it with `pd.to_datetime` seems to work:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['6/5/2016', '7/5/2016', '7/5/2016', '7/5/2016', '9/5/2016', '9/5/2016', '9/5/2016', '9/5/2016', '5/13/2016', '5/14/2016', '5/14/2016'])

In [12]: pd.to_datetime(s)
Out[12]:
0    2016-06-05
1    2016-07-05
2    2016-07-05
3    2016-07-05
4    2016-09-05
5    2016-09-05
6    2016-09-05
7    2016-09-05
8    2016-05-13
9    2016-05-14
10   2016-05-14
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note: If you had a consistent format you can pass it in explicitly:

```
In [13]: pd.to_datetime(s, format="%m/%d/%Y")
Out[13]:
0    2016-06-05
1    2016-07-05
2    2016-07-05
3    2016-07-05
4    2016-09-05
5    2016-09-05
6    2016-09-05
7    2016-09-05
8    2016-05-13
9    2016-05-14
10   2016-05-14
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying !  
The dates that I have posted are actually for month of may. But pd.to_datetime() understands 7/5/2014 as 5th July 2016. 
I understand that it is impossible to distinguish between 6/4/2016 and 5/6/2016, if we look at them alone. However, I was hoping that the fact the dates are in ascending order and the actual dataset is spread for over a year, there would be a method to make sense of it. Are you aware of any function that could use this fact and make sense of the dates ?

Comment: You can use `dayfirst=True` (but that won't solve for ambiguity). Let me have a little think about being monotonic. Edit: It's rough cos brute forcing (to find a monotonic solution) is potentially 2^N (or more likely 2 ^ (N/3) as most dates are non-ambiguous).